# Left shift operation with Ones' complement binary

Tags: binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, negative-number, ones-complement

I'm in researching about bitwise operation and signed number representations​. I've recognized that if we do left shift on ones' complement pattern. It does not correctly multiply the original number.

For example (Ones' complement):

```
11100101 (-26) << 1 = 11001010 (-53)

11110100 (-11) << 2 = 11010000 (-47)
```

-26 left shift 1 bit give -53 (not -52), -11 left shift 2 bits give -47 (not -44). So is this a reason why people choose two's complement for precision number operation. I've searched on google but no post mention about the left shift and ones' complement. Almost mention left shift with two's complement

Comment: In C and C++ it simply doesn't matter. If you left shift a negative number, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, so in C or C++, it does not support left shift a negative number, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two's complement, a negative number A is coded by the positive number 2<sup>n</sup>-|A| and it is possible to find its value by  -2<sup>n-1</sup> × a<sub>n-1</sub> + ∑<sub>0</sub><sup>n-2</sup> 2<sup>i</sup> × a<sub>i</sub> It is easy to show that shifting this value left by k bits will give the code of A×2<sup>k</sup>, provided there is no overflow (ie only zeroes or only ones are shifted out).

In ones complement, a negative number A is coded by (2's complement of A)-1. Its value is -2<sup>n-1</sup> × a<sub>n-1</sub> + ∑<sub>0</sub><sup>n-2</sup> 2<sup>i</sup> × a<sub>i</sub>-1. If we left shift it by k, the numeric value of the result is (2's complement of 2<sup>k</sup>*A)-2<sup>k</sup>*1  (provided there is no overflow). It is different by 2<sup>k</sup>-1 from the expected result which would be (2's complement of 2<sup>k</sup>*A)-1

We can verify it on your examples:

> C1(-26)<<1=-53(=-52-(2<sup>1</sup>-1))
>   C1(-11)<<2=-47(=-44-(2<sup>2</sup>-1))

So to multiply a negative number coded in 1's complement by 2<sup>k</sup>, you need to left shift it by k and to add to your result 2<sup>k</sup>-1

In general, only two's complement gives simple arithmetic operations. Other codes (excess k, one's complement, sign absolute value) always require a correction (and it is the reason why they are very rarely used).

Comment: Thanks for your useful explanation, but it may be a minor confused that as I know ones' complement negative number A is coded by (2's complement of A) - 1 (as you said as (2's complement of A) + 1). Which is correct

Comment: You are right. A usual negative number A is indeed coded in two complement as C2(A)=~A+1. One complement is ~A and is hence C2(A)-1. Thanks. I clarified the answer.